# Select all items for category and all from its subcategories

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to build my own webshop.
I have two tables - products and categories. The structure is like that :

---

```
categories :
id       name       parent_id
```

---

```
products :
id       title      category_id
```

---

At the moment when the user clicks on main category I'm selecting products to display like that :

```
url : www.mypage.com/?category_id=1
sql : 'SELECT * FROM products WHERE category_id = 1'
```

The problem is that I'd like to make it when the user clicks on main category to select also all the products from its child categories. For example category `Family` is sub category of category `Cars` and in the db looks like that

```
categories :
id       name       parent_id  
1        'Cars'     0
2        'Family'   1  
3        'Sport'    1  

products :
id       title      category_id  
1        'Ferrari'  3 
2        'Honda'    2
```

As you can see my current select will not select `Ferrari` or `Honda` because the user is looking at category with `id=1`...
How to modify my select so it will display all products from the child categories of the main category?

Comment: you should look into recursive select query in mysql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"SELECT * FROM products WHERE category_id = '$your_category_id'
OR category_id IN (
  SELECT parent_id FROM categories 
    WHERE id = '$your_category_id'
)"
```

Note: This example is only for two level depth.

e.g.

```
Ferrari > Cars
```

Its not for more than two levels.

e.g.

```
Ferrari Child Category > Ferrari > Cars
```

Comment: Ok, thanks I will try that in few minutes. But I have deeper than 2 levels nested categories... how can I make it work for that ?

Answer (score 2):

If you have more than two levels in category tree, you'll need a separate table (sometimes referred as Closure table) which will have reference of each category and it's ancestor / descending categories. Check this link for examples: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/transitive-closure-table

Answer (score 1):

If the hierarchy is only one level deep, you can modify the query like this...

```
SELECT * FROM Products WHERE Category_id IN (
    SELECT Id 
    FROM Categories 
    WHERE Id = 1 OR parent_id = 1)
```

Hope that helps